# htaccess URL redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

How can i redirect some URLs to different format.

```
http://mysite.com/mydir1/mydir2/my-article-first-86974.html
http://mysite.com/mydir1/somefolder/my-article-76674.html
http://mysite.com/mydir1/anotherfolder/some-text-35667.html
http://mysite.com/mydir1/mydir6/my-article-another-75445.html
```

I want to redirect the above URLs to below format.

```
http://mysite.com/mydir2/my-article-first-1-86974.html
http://mysite.com/somefolder/my-article-1-76674.html
http://mysite.com/anotherfolder/some-text-1-35667.html
http://mysite.com/mydir6/my-article-another-1-75445.html
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find a basic htaccess tutorial online? This doesn't look complex at all... What have you attempted?

Comment: I have made some changes in my question and i couldn't find the solution in any tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^mydir1/([^/]+)/(.+?)-(\d+\.html)$ /$1/$2-1-$3 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks. I cannot use the word 'my-article' and 'mydir2' in rule, because it will be different in all URLS. Please see the new changes in question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but it is not adding '-1' in url before the number. i.e my-article-first-86974.html should change to my-article-first-1-86974.html.

Comment: Ah I overlooked that `-1` requirement, sorry editing it again.

Answer (score 1):

Should be like:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^mydir(.*)/(.*)/([a-z\-]{2,}([a-z\-][\d])[\d])(.*)$ $2/$3$1-$4 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. I cannot use the word 'my-article' in rule, because, it will be different in all URLS. Please see the new changes in question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it is not working, it is not adding '-1' in url before the number. i.e my-article-first-86974.html should change to my-article-first-1-86974.html, it is not happening.

Comment: I tried the latest rule which you have given, but it is not making any change in URL.

Comment: URL redirecting without `1`? Like: `my-article-first-86974.html`?

Comment: @Saritha It have to work. Updated again. Redirecting where now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something along these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/mydir2/(.*)+$ /mydir1/mydir2/$1
```

Comment: redirecting `my-article-1`

Comment: Thanks, i have made some changes in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your htacces :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine   On
        RewriteBase http://mysite.com 
        RewriteRule     ^/(.+)$ /mydir1/mydir2/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note : this code is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    # SEO URL Settings
    RewriteEngine On
    # If your installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
    RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

you can see this  `RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]`

**NOTE:CODE NOT TESTED**

Comment: Thanks. I cannot use the word 'my-article' and 'mydir2' in rule, because it will be different in all URLS. Please see the new changes in question.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your answer, it is affecting all the URLs in my project, i just want to redirect URLs starts with http://mysite.com/mydir1/.......